# Command works only when user ran it, not with eval

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, java

I'm trying to automate build. I made a complete script which can be seen [here](https://github.com/Elikill58/Negativity/blob/dd378b267a8fcefe6272c4a6ff9dd4755fe8484f/setup_spigot.sh), but I made a minimal example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

trap "exit" INT

DIR="spigot/spigotJars/install"
if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
   echo "$DIR already created" > /dev/null
else
   mkdir -p $DIR
   chmod -R +x $DIR
fi
cd $DIR || exit

extension=.tar.gz
executable=

export IFS=";"
java8=unknown

function installJDK() {
   echo "Failed to find Java $1. Downloading it..."
   curl -L -o "Java$1$extension" "$2"
   mkdir "jdk-$1"
   if [[ $extension == ".zip" ]]; then
      unzip "Java$1$extension" -d "jdk-$1"
   else
      tar -xvf "Java$1$extension" -C "jdk-$1" --strip-components 1
   fi
   rm "Java$1$extension"
}

if [[ $java8 == *"unknown"* ]]; then
    if [ -d "./jdk-8" ]; then
        echo "Java 8 and already downloaded, using this version..."
    else
        installJDK 8 "https://github.com/adoptium/temurin8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u345-b01/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_${os}_hotspot_8u345b01$extension"
    fi
    java8="$PWD/jdk-8/bin/java$executable"
fi


curl -o BuildTools.jar https://hub.spigotmc.org/jenkins/job/BuildTools/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/target/BuildTools.jar

mcCmd="\"$java8\" -jar BuildTools.jar --rev 1.8.8"
echo "Running $mcCmd ..."
eval "$mcCmd"
```

With this script, I got this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class  -Xmx1024M
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running command, return status !=0: [sh, /home/tmp/Negativity/spigot/spigotJars/install/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin/mvn, -Dbt.name=582a, install:install-file, -Dfile=work/mapped.ba9a3cce.jar, -Dpackaging=jar, -DgroupId=org.spigotmc, -DartifactId=minecraft-server, -Dversion=1.8.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Builder.runProcess0(Builder.java:973)
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Builder.runProcess(Builder.java:904)
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Builder.runMaven(Builder.java:873)
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Builder.main(Builder.java:552)
        at org.spigotmc.builder.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:27)
```

But, when I run manually the command (for me, `"/home/tmp/spigot/spigotJars/install/jdk-8/bin/java" -jar BuildTools.jar --rev 1.8.8`) it works fine.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Bad practices: (1) Unquoted `$DIR` in `mkdir -p $DIR` and few other places only works because your `$DIR` is a static string that happens to be "safe". If you ever change it to a less fortunate value then the bug will bite you. (2) `export IFS=";"` may affect any descendant. I really don't know if this is the culprit. Before running the command manually, do you `export IFS=";"` like in the script? I guess not. I haven't analyzed what you need this `export` for, but in general a non-default value of `IFS` left in the environment inherited by children is potentially harmful.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I will change for `$DIR`. Also, for `export IFS=";"`, if I well remember it's for JAVA_HOME variable (which is not in the copied part, but it's in the full code link)

Comment: @Elikill58 Does the problem go away if you remove or reset the change to `IFS`? Does it fail if you run `export IFS=";"` in your interactive shell before testing it?

Comment: I removed it for Linux users, and it works fine yes !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from `export IFS=";"`. As it's a fix for Windows users, I made a check about if it's from linux or windows env.

Here is the code (truncated) I made:

```bash
case "$OSTYPE" in
  solaris*) os=solaris ;;
  darwin*)  os=macos ;;
  linux*)   os=linux ;;
  bsd*)     os=bsd ;;
  msys*)    os=windows ;;
  cygwin*)  os=windows ;;
  *)        os=unknown:$OSTYPE ;;
esac


if [[ $os == "windows" ]]; then
   extension=.zip
   executable=.exe
   export IFS=";"
fi
echo "OS used: $os"
```

Then now it's working for everyone.